# HBaseLocalCluster : Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster

Tags: junit, hbase

I'm trying to use a hbase local cluster instance for junit purpose, but getting the below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Shutting down
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.init(MiniHBaseCluster.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:68)
at com.github.sakserv.minicluster.impl.HbaseLocalCluster.start(HbaseLocalCluster.java:215)
at com.test.TestTopology.setUp(TestTopology.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.init(MiniHBaseCluster.java:214)
... 27 more

Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.source.JvmMetrics.getEventCounters(JvmMetrics.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.source.JvmMetrics.getMetrics(JvmMetrics.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMetrics(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.updateJmxCache(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.getMBeanInfo(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:155)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getNewMBeanClassName(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:333)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:319)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.register(MBeans.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.startMBeans(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter.start(MetricsSourceAdapter.java:100)
```

I'm using the version hadoop-mini-clusters from com.github.sakserv 0.1.11 version. Also, I'm not getting issue when usng zookeeper and Kafka mini clusters. The problem is coming with Hbase mini cluster only.

Also, this is how I'm invoking this mini cluster.

```
         HbaseLocalCluster hbaseLocalCluster = new HbaseLocalCluster.Builder()
             .setHbaseMasterPort(25111).setHbaseMasterInfoPort(-1)
             .setNumRegionServers(1).setHbaseRootDir("./embedded_hbase")
             .setZookeeperPort(6195)
             .setZookeeperConnectionString("localhost:" + 6195)
             .setZookeeperZnodeParent("/hbase-unsecure")
             .setHbaseWalReplicationEnabled(false)
             .setHbaseConfiguration(new Configuration()).build();
      hbaseLocalCluster.start();
```

Can someone please help me. TIA

Comment: What  is your $HADOOP_HOME set to? please see if changing localhost to actual IP helps.

Comment: I changed that to localhost also and tried, but error is same. HADOOP_HOME is set properly to C:\hadoop-2.7.1

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class" looks like you have some incompatible jars included, there might be some conflicting jars in your classpath

Comment: @user3497321 - Hi, were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same problem now